# Concern about point-vector specification of a line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Suppose one is asked for a vector equation of a line, and one has only one point given along with a parallel vector. Why does $\vec{r}_0$ equal the point given?

Dont vectors require at least two points to determine what the vector is. Does one just assume that the other point is the origin in such a case? Will that assumption ever be dangerous? It seems like it could be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this supposed to be "the vector equation _of a line_"? This would make sense from context but it should be specified.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes it is. Thank you for the help in clarifying my question!

Comment: Short answer. Yes, the "other point" is the origin. No, this is not dangerous. The context will always make the meaning clear.

Comment: thank you @EthanBolker